# Was Vasishtha's Brahmadanda a weapon or was it an embodiment of a Brahmin's Tapas?

Tags: weapon, vashishta, vishwamitra

"danda" just means stick - so it is unlikely that it was a weapon.  So when vishwamitra attacked vasishtha - did Vasishtha just use his stick to focus the power of his tapas to repel Vishwamitra's weapons?

Comment: It has been made by Brahmã (ब्रह्मा) himself. Not just mere tapas. Although, it does require extreme tapas to behold it.

Comment: I think this was a weapon though in stick form which emits some rays which could consumes everything including missiles..